# TypeError: props.items is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

What does this mean that the props.items are undefined? The parent component is supposed to pass the data down to the Users component. I've checked the Users component is correctly receiving the object with the data. So is there something wrong with the syntax in the JSX?

The error message:

```
TypeError: props.items is undefined
Users
C:/...src/components/Users/Users.js:3

  1 | function Users(props) {
  2 |   return (
> 3 |     <ul>
  4 |       {props.items.map((user) => (
  5 |         <div>
  6 |           {user.name} - {user.age}
```

The parent component:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import Card from './components/UI/Card';
import Form from './components/Form/Form';
import users from './data/data';
import Users from './components/Users/Users';

function App() {
  const [userDB, setUserDB] = useState(users);
  function addUserToDB(user) {
    setUserDB(prevUsers => {
      return [user, ...prevUsers];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Card>
        <Form onAddToDB={addUserToDB} />
      </Card>
      <Users userData={userDB} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The Users component where the error traces to:

```
function Users(props) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.items.map((user) => (
        <div>
          {user.name} - {user.age}
        </div>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default Users;
```

Comment: `<Users userData={userDB} />` - where do _you_ think the `items` prop is coming from?

Comment: *"What does this mean that the props.items are undefined?"* It means that the component doesn't receive a value for the `items` prop. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: it looks like the prop name the users component is getting is called "userData" so the code in users component should be - props.userData.map((user)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed to pass the **items** prop to your **Users** or you should rename the **userData** prop.

```
      <Users items={userDB} />
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are passing will ultimately comes inside props

Here

```
<Users userData={userDB} />
```

so props contains userData object only

so instead of

```
{props.items.map((user) => (...)
```

use

```
 {props.userData.map((user) => (...)
```